# Getting 404 error in postman when tryin to invoke a Rest DSL in apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying a simple rest service using apache camel with 'get' as http verb.

```
package com.ApacheCamelTraining.camelmicroservicea.routes.b;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class MyFileRouter extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        
        restConfiguration().component("servlet")
            .host("localhost").port(8080);
        
        rest("say/hello")
        
            .get().route().transform().constant("Hello World!")
            //.post().to("file:files/sayHello")
    ;
        
        from("file:files/input")
        .log("${body}")
        .to("file:files/output");
        
    }

}
```

I am trying this in postman: `http://localhost:8080/demo/camel/say/hello` 'demo' is added because of the context path in the application.properties file, noting that this file was empty until I added the following :

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
```

and 'camel' is because CamelServlet is by default set to “/camel”

Please find below my dependencies:
camel core: 3.11.1
camel-servlet: 3.11.1
camel-service-starter:3.11.1
camel-servlet-starter:3.0.0-RC3
camel-http-common:3.11.1
camel-spring-boot-starter:3.11.1

and finally this is what my console shows when I run my application

```
2021-09-13 11:02:06.117  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] c.A.c.CamelMicroserviceAApplication      : Starting CamelMicroserviceAApplication using Java 11.0.12 on E210 with PID 20392 (D:\Users\User\MyFiles\Apache Camel github\Apache Camel Youtube Training\camel-microservice-a\target\classes started by User in D:\Users\User\MyFiles\Apache Camel github\Apache Camel Youtube Training\camel-microservice-a)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.117  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] c.A.c.CamelMicroserviceAApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-13 11:02:06.302  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.303  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-13 11:02:06.303  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-09-13 11:02:06.330  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/demo]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-13 11:02:06.330  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 212 ms
2021-09-13 11:02:06.422  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-09-13 11:02:06.424  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-09-13 11:02:06.432  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/demo'
2021-09-13 11:02:06.455  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.b.CamelSpringBootApplicationListener : Starting CamelMainRunController to ensure the main thread keeps running
2021-09-13 11:02:06.456  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup summary (total:2 started:2)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.456  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started route32 (file://files/input)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.456  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started route33 (rest://get:say/hello)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.456  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.11.1 (camel-15) started in 20ms (build:2ms init:17ms start:1ms)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.456  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] c.A.c.CamelMicroserviceAApplication      : Started CamelMicroserviceAApplication in 0.35 seconds (JVM running for 1966.925)
2021-09-13 11:02:06.457  INFO 20392 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2021-09-13 11:03:34.724  INFO 20392 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/demo]   : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-13 11:03:34.724  INFO 20392 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-13 11:03:34.726  INFO 20392 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

This is the error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-09-13T12:55:34.581+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/demo/say/hello"
}
```

Thank you I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

To set the context path you must use the following property:

```
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path
```

or in yaml:

```
camel:
  servlet:
    mapping:
      context-path:
```

See https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/servlet-component.html#_sb_option_camel_servlet_mapping_context-path

I assume you migrated from Camel 2 to Camel 3 because the [Camel 2 property](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/servlet-component.html#_usage_2) was

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path
```

The different Camel demo repos have proven to be very helpful to me:

- Camel Spring Boot:
  https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples
- Camel Core: https://github.com/apache/camel-examples

I found the solution for your specific case here: https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/rest-swagger